# Implicitly watching $rootScope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to watch over one of $rootScope variable.

It works and update **bar**  when I explicitly register a watcher:

```
$rootScope.$watch('foo', function(newVal) {
  $scope.bar = newVal;
});
```

But it does not update when I just assign **bar** to $rootScope's **foo**. Shouldn't it implicitly assign a watcher for this expression?

```
$scope.bar = $rootScope.foo;
```

By the way, **foo** is initially an empty object, and it is updated to *{'test': 'something'}* later.

**UPDATE**

It is now clear that this expression won't assign a watcher and update itself. So, is there any way to update **bar** without a watch function in controller?

Are promises available for this purpose? I think [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) can do it like this:

```
$scope.list = Restangular.all('accounts').getList().$object;
```

Comment: nope. thats just an assignment.

Comment: yes, it appears this was a silly question :) I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No because that's not how javascript works. If you tried something like this outside of angular, you would see nothing would update:

```
var temp = 4;
var temp2 = temp;

temp = 5;
console.log(temp2); //outputs 4
```

The reason it does work for other things (such as objects) is because they are referenced. This example would work:

```
var temp = { value: 4 };
var temp2 = temp;

temp.value = 5;
console.log(temp2); //outputs { value: 5 }
```

**Edit**

Without seeing the rest of your code and based off your comment, i'm going to assume you destroyed your reference. While my example above would work, this one won't:

```
var temp = { value: 4 };
var temp2 = temp;

temp = { value: 5 };
console.log(temp2); //outputs { value: 4 }
```

Comment: Thanks Mathew, but my foo was an object actually. It's initial value is {}, and updated value is {'label': 'test'}. I updated my question anyway.